# Rails: How to query in a join table with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a table Master which has many Jobs. I am trying to find out how many has more than 1 job.

I am doing this:

```
a = Master.all.select {|c| c.jobs.count > 0 }
a.count
```

Is this the correct way?

Also I want to find out recurring users so I want to query each Master's first and last job and see if they're greater than a month. How would I do that? I'm confused.

```
Master.all.select {|c| (c.jobs.last.date - c.jobs.first.date > 30 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you can removed your `N+1` query as:

```
 a = Master.includes(:jobs).select {|c| c.jobs.count > 0 }
```

Otherwise use database query as if you are using this query it only returns conditional records

```
 a = Master.includes(:jobs).group("jobs.id").having("count(jobs.id) > 0")
```

For second query you can used same way just add `includes` to removed `N+1` query and it is best way to find

```
 Master.includes(:jobs).select {|c| (c.jobs.last.date - c.jobs.first.date > 30 }
```

You can used for jobs master whose jobs not available because `includes` use `left outer join`

```
Master.includes(:jobs).where("jobs.master_id = masters.id").select {|c| (c.jobs.last.date - c.jobs.first.date > 30 }
```

Comment: how come I'm getting NoMethodError: undefined method `date' for nil:NilClass

Comment: it's happening when some master don't have jobs, so master.jobs.last or first is nil, what can i do

Comment: it's giving me "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "jobs""

Comment: @ShinonChan it works perfectly just verify your table name

Answer (score 1):

you can try simply

```
 Master.joins(:jobs).group("jobs.id").having("count(jobs.id) > ?",0)
```

or m[etawhere](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_where)

```
 Master.includes(:jobs).where(:jobs => {:count.gt => 0})
```

For the second query you need a `Master` to complete the difference its job first and last date.

Like

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :jobs
   scope :date_diff, -> {(include(:jobs).where((jobs.first.date - jobs.last.date).to_i > 30) }
 end
```

Now

```
Master.find(2).date_diff
```

Comment: sure is this give correct answer?? because `where` not allow any type of `aggregate` function.

Comment: @VishalJAIN see the gem please metawhere in Arel way

Answer (score 0):

```
Master.includes(:jobs).reject { |m| m.jobs.count == 0 }.count
```

For the second part.

```
Master.joins(:jobs).where("DATEDIFF((Select jobs.date FROM jobs where id = (Select MAX(id) FROM jobs)),(Select jobs.date from jobs where id = (Select MIN(id) FROM jobs))) > ?", 30)
```

Comment: @Rubysmith is this query worked? `jobs.count` is not allow in `where `clause

Answer (score 0):

```
  a = Master.joins(:jobs)
```

All master with jobs(in this query master that have no job will be removed)

```
 month_jobs =  Master.joins(:jobs).select {|c| (c.jobs.last.date - c.jobs.first.date > 30 }
```

Comment: hey `joins` not supports `eager load` used `includes` with condition